# Document onclick function needs to open a new page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made an app for fivem server (GTA) This is an emergency services app where players can choose who to call. But my problem is when I open the app I already see the screen which should only happen when I click on police or ambulance.

I'm new to javascript so i dont know how to fix this can someone help me out of this?

My html code:

```html
                    <div class="emergency-app">
                        <div class="emergency-app-header"><p>Meldkamer</p></div>
                            
                        <div class="emergency-app-tab-appereance">
                            <div class="emergency-app-tab-header"><p>Heb je een noodgeval? Bel ons!</p></div>
                            <div class="emergency-app-tab" data-emergencytab="policeapp">
                                <img src="./img/politie.png" class="settings-tab-icon">
                                <div class="emergency-tab-title"><p>Politie</p></div>
                                <div class="emergency-tab-description"><p>Waakzaam en dienstbaar</p></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="emergency-app-tab" data-emergencytab="ambulanceapp">
                                 <img src="./img/ambulance.png" class="settings-tab-icon">
                                 <div class="emergency-tab-title"><p>Ambulance</p></div>
                                <div class="emergency-tab-description"><p>We helpen je er doorheen!</p></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="emergency-app-tab" data-emergencytab="mechanicapp">
                                <img src="./img/anwb.png" class="settings-tab-icon">
                                <div class="emergency-tab-title"><p>Wegenwacht</p></div>
                                <div class="emergency-tab-description"><p>Brengt je verder</p></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="emergency-app-tab" data-emergencytab="fireapp">
                                <img src="./img/brandweer.png" class="settings-tab-icon">
                                <div class="emergency-tab-title"><p>Brandweer</p></div>
                                <div class="emergency-tab-description"><p>Waar u naar buiten rent gaan wij naar binnen</p></div>
                            </div>                                
                        </div>

                        <div class="emergency-policeapp-tab">
                            <div class="emergency-app-header"><p>Achtergrond</p></div>

                            <div class="background-options">
                                <div class="background-option" data-background="default-qbus">
                                    <div class="background-option-icon"> <i class="fas fa-paint-brush"></i> </div>
                                    <div class="background-option-title">Standaard </div>
                                    <div class="background-option-description"> Standaard achtergrond </div>
                                    <div class="background-option-current"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My JS code:

```js
MI.Phone.Settings = {};
MI.Phone.Settings.OpenedTab = null;


var PressedBackground = null;
var IsChecked = null;


$(document).on('click', '.emergency-app-tab', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var PressedTab = $(this).data("emergencytab");

    if (PressedTab == "policeapp") {
        MI.Phone.Animations.TopSlideDown(".emergency-"+PressedTab+"-tab", 200, 0);
        MI.Phone.Settings.OpenedTab = PressedTab;
    } else if (PressedTab == "ambulanceapp") {
        MI.Phone.Animations.TopSlideDown(".emergency-"+PressedTab+"-tab", 200, 0);
        MI.Phone.Settings.OpenedTab = PressedTab;
    }
});
```

```css
.emergency-app {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere you're initially hiding the DOM elements that supply your html, is that missing from the snippet or are you just forgetting to toggle `display="none"` on init and `display="block"` (or activating slidedown anim or whatever) when your `if` condition is satisfied to display your DOM elements? If you're missing that part entirely it would explain why you see it (`<div class="emergency-app">` this) immediately without having to actually click anything.

Comment: I think i missing it or something dont know what you mean.

I have on the css file look in the post above a class emergency-app class

with that code

Comment: That's a nice library you use, which is it?

Comment: If you have a reproducible example I'm guessing it's either something is overwriting your css `display:none` (you can check with right-click -> inspect and see the css inheritances for that parent element) or something else not evident just seeing what's shared. Or at least imo.

Comment: I fixed it.  I make a big mistake on the css... and yeah it was the display: none.  It was overwrithing